# In AWS EKS, how to install and access etcd, kube-apiserver, and other things?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am learning AWS EKS now and I want to know how to access etcd, kube-apiserver and other control plane components?

For example, when we run command as below in minikube, we can find `etcd-minikube`,`kube-apiserver-minikube`

```sh
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces 
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-lrt6z           1/1     Running   0          176d
kube-system   coredns-6955765f44-xbtc2           1/1     Running   1          176d
kube-system   etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   1          176d
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube        1/1     Running   1          176d
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   1          176d
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   1          176d
kube-system   kube-proxy-69mqp                   1/1     Running   1          176d
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   1          176d
kube-system   storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   2          176d
```

And then, we can access them by below command:

```sh
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ kubectl exec -it -n kube-system kube-apiserver-minikube -- /bin/sh
# kube-apiserver
W0715 13:56:17.176154      21 services.go:37] No CIDR for service cluster IPs specified. 
...
```

**My question: I want to do something like the above example in AWS EKS, but I cannot find `kube-apiserver`**

```sh
xiaojie@ubuntu:~/environment/calico_resources$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces 
NAMESPACE     NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   aws-node-flv95            1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-system   aws-node-kpkv9            1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-system   aws-node-rxztq            1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-system   coredns-cdd78ff87-bjnmg   1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-system   coredns-cdd78ff87-f7rl4   1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-system   kube-proxy-5wv5m          1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-system   kube-proxy-6846w          1/1     Running   0          23h
kube-system   kube-proxy-9rbk4          1/1     Running   0          23h
```

Answer (score 16):

AWS EKS is a managed kubernetes offering. Kubernetes control plane components such as API Server, ETCD are installed, managed and upgraded by AWS. Hence you can neither see these components nor can `exec` into these components.

In AWS EKS you can only play with the worker nodes

Answer (score 8):

- **You** are at the **left** ... **AWS** is at the **right**
- EKS is not a managed service for the whole kubernetes cluster.
- EKS is a **managed service** only for **Kubernetes Master nodes**.

[image]

That's why, it's worth to operate EKS with tools (.e.g; terraform) that helps provisioning the whole cluster in no time .. as explained [here](https://www.udemy.com/course/aws-eks-kubernetes/).

Answer (score 1):

As what Arghya Sadhu and Abdennour TOUMI said, EKS Encapsulates most Control Plane Components but kube-proxy, See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/index.html).

> Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service (Amazon EKS) is a managed service that makes it easy for you to run Kubernetes on AWS without needing to stand up or maintain your own Kubernetes control plane.

So, I have tried to find the way to configure these Components instead of accessing these container and input command, but finally I give up. See this [Github issue](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/176).